# Plotly Bar Chart Axes

Tags: charts, plotly-dash, axis, axis-labels

Im trying to create a simple bar chart and deploy it within a dropdown menu. My problem is with the axes. I do not know why when I use px.bar the deploy just take one variable (x or y) and make the plot, but when I use px.scatter it works, it takes both variables.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output 
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

app = Dash(__name__)

pf = fr.iloc[2:10,18:25]
pf.columns = [prueba1]
pf.index = ['CH + CHL','CH','CHL(UST)','CHL','CL + CHL','CL','CHL(UST)','CHL']


app.layout = html.Div(children=[
html.Div([dcc.Dropdown(pf.index,'CH', id='pandas-dropdown-2'),
html.Div(id='pandas-output-container')]),

dcc.Graph(id='example-graph')
])
Output('example-graph','figure'),
Input('pandas-dropdown-2', 'value'))


def update_graph(value_input):
    pff = pf[pf.index == value_input]
    fig = px.bar(pff, x = np.array(prueba1), y = list(pff.values))#,
return fig

__name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

The result is this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91J5A.png)

Why the Y label is count instead of years?

But when I change from px.bar to px.scatter this happens:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFHPv.png)

It works!!! But I need the bar chart!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello! My problem is with Bar chart. I want to graph a bar chart with the variables prueba1 and pff.values. Prueba 1 is a list of years and pff.values are the measurement from those years. I do not know why when I use px.bar the result graph just take the pff.values and not the prueba1 values. If you see the result graph the y axis is count and the x axis is value. What I want for my final result is on x axis the years value (prueba1) and on y axis the measurement (pff.values)! Thank you for your answer! @Community